# @google-cloud/speech node modules being created with v64-darwin, v51 needed

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I am creating a panel in Adobe Premiere Pro which used Google Cloud speech. I am accessing google-cloud/speech on the Javascript side, not JSX side via NodeJS.  I am also accessing google-cloud/storage.  No big deal, I installed NodeJS on a Mac and functions accessing google-cloud/storage were easy to code.

After following the instructions to `npm --save @google-cloud/speech` and `npm --save @google-cloud/storage`, it created `the node_modules` directory.  I have moved them to a custom directory but they are duplicated in the standard location also.

In my code, I reference them as per the google-cloud examples:

```
// note cep.node is required in the Adobe CEP environment to access nodejs
    const speech = cep_node.require(extention_path+'/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech');
const project_id ='project_id_xxx1234';
const keyFilePath = extention_path +'/path/to/key.json';

const client = new speech.v1.SpeechClient({
      projectId: project_id,
      keyFilename: keyFilePath,
});
```

I've tried this w/o the ids and speech.SpeechClient() etc as per examples.  The methodology is working fine with google-cloud/storage, so I know the similar downloaded node modules at the same location work fine for that.

However, it fails on trying to make a new `speech.SpeechClient()` with the browser debug error below.

> Uncaught Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
>   **Expected directory**: node-v51-darwin-x64-unknown
>   **Found:** [.DS_Store, node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown]
>   This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
>   Original error: Cannot find module '/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CEP/extensions/com.iv.PProPanel/lib/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v51-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node'
>       at Object. (/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CEP/extensions/com.iv.PProPanel/lib/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:53:17)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:595:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:610:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:512:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:471:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:463:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:522:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CEP/extensions/com.iv.PProPanel/lib/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:145:12)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:595:32)

My belief is that these series of node_modules that are accessed by @google-cloud/speech were compiled use NODE_MODULE_64 and need 51 (instead).

`$ npm rebuild`  rebuilds (or checks current version of the modules) fine with the exception

> protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall /Library/Application Support/Adobe/CEP/extensions/com.iv.PProPanel/lib/node_modules/protobufjs
>   node scripts/postinstall
>   grpc@1.14.1 install /Library/Application Support/Adobe/CEP/extensions/com.iv.PProPanel/lib/node_modules/grpc
>   node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
>   [grpc] Success: "/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CEP/extensions/com.iv.PProPanel/lib/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" already installed
>   Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

So some module needs v51 instead of the build v64. The question is can the @google-cloud/speech modules be built using v51 and how? or do I wait for google-cloud to come up with a solution? BTW: I also renamed the node-v64 dir to node-51, but received another error referencing the MODULE 51. Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the dependencies for @google-cloud/speech are [native addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html). Those being C/C++ code, they need to be compiled for the correct Node version. Looks like your Node version that you used for `npm install` doesn't match the one in Adobe CEP. Switch to Node 5.1 and run `npm install` or `npm rebuild` again.

I recommend using `nvm` to change Node versions, see [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Comment: Thank you user835611 for the insight.  I downloaded nvm via:

Comment: Thank you user 835611. I downloaded nvm, great tip! Installed it and recompiled the node_modules w nodejs 7.10.0, which is the latest version to create the v51-darwin-x64 dir.  On my Mac, building the node_modules @google-cloud/speech with any nodejs greater than version 7.10.0 results in a grpc... extensions directory with a V greater than 51, therefore the extension_binary/node-v.XX-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node can not be accessed.  Hacking the dir name to v51 causes other errors. Building w 7.10.0 creates the correct dir, but function is limited/non-existant.    Waiting for google.

Comment: What Node version is Adobe CEP using? You need to use the exact same Node version to build the modules.

Comment: You can find out by executing `console.log(process.version)` in that environment.

Comment: Thanks 835611 also for the nvm tip.  I did that, and Adobe CEP is using 7.7.4 may be upgrading?  It may be that some google nodes are more recent, and can't be utilized by node 7.7.4? At least nvm has allowed me to experiment and try to debug.  Building/using 7.7.4 has created "internal/process/warning.js:21 (node:48372) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead" which I don't know how to do/ work around. It also reloads my html page after the function completes. I may have to access via the REST API.  Rather use Node. thoughts?